# Kali Linux VirtualBox browsers crash

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, firefox, chrome, crash

No matter what I do, the browsers of my **Kali Linux VM** crash. I have tried **Firefox ESR** (**preinstalled**), **Firefox**, **Google Chrome**, and **Chromium**. In Firefox the whole browser crashes (max 1-2 mins after starting and using it) and on the chromium-based browsers only the Tabs crash, without any error message. When I start Firefox from the command line I receive this as error message, when it crashes:

```
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
8253
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
```

I use **VirtualBox** and installed Kali Linux several times with these two options (each with the settings of the Documentation):

- Using [Kali Linux prebuilt Virtual Machines](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines)
- Installing the Kali Linux [with an image](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-installer-images)

In the VMs I also ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and I checked the browser for updates. Furthermore, many clean installations didn't work.
Of course, I have tried to look up this issue. But I didn't find anything from the last few years.

My question is what am I missing? Why does the standard browser not work on a prebuilt Virtual Machine? And why are the others also crashing? Thank you for helping me!

Comment: I wasn't able to fix this issue, but using VMWare and the prebuilt VM from kali.org works for me fine.